# what is included in the localization and internationalization?

Tags: localization

i have read many thing for localization  and internationalization.from Wikipedia i got that  A localized system has been adapted or converted for use in a particular locale  including the language of  the user interface (UI), input, and display, and features such as time/date display and currency. internationalized system is equipped for use in a range of "locales"  by allowing the co-existence of several languages and character sets for input, display, and UI.

> instead of this reading i got confusion that ,we are creating resource file which store Local  language UI  .so,this process is what   I18N or L10N.

can any one explain me with reason and explanation?

Comment: This seems to be a question about the use of words, about naming things, rather than about programming even in a broad sense. Use whatever words are generally used in your environment. If they ask your opinion about this (they probably don’t), say that you would call setting up a system with resource files internationalization, whereas creating a particular resource file is localization.

Comment: for example,in drop down box specified list of language and according to chosen language UI changed is Internationalization and at the time of programming creating specified  language's resource file is localization . is it true which i understand from your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything to do with resources is localization.

There are other things that need to be done in order to internationalize an application (i.e. making it "world-ready"), such as handling input and output according to the format rules defined by your end user's locale. But none of these other concerns can be addressed by resources. Resources merely provide translated content.

People often use the term "localization" when they mean "internationalization". But Localization (L8N) is just one subset of Internationalization (I8N).